# Не поднимается postgres 13 в docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgresql13

перезагрузили проект в docker и появилась ошибка с postgres в docker.
Перед этим был установлен postgres на машину вне докера.
То есть, был поднят проект в docker с БД в docker, после чего был установлен отдельно postgres вне докера, после чего после перезагрузки проекта появилась ошибка. Как я понял postgres в докере пытается обратится к локальному /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 и из за этого ошибка. volumes прокинуты в docker-compose файле: postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

Нужна помощь в решении данной проблемы с сохранением данных в БД которая была в докере

Ниже прикрепил вывод docker-compose logs

```bash
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.536 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.0 (Debian 13.0-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.536 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.536 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.537 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.539 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-11-22 15:50:06 UTC
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.539 UTC [26] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.539 UTC [26] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.969 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 26) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.969 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
project_db_1     | 2022-11-22 17:00:45.982 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
project_db_1     | 
project_db_1     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
```

Comment: У вас испорчены файлы WAL. Зайдите в контейнер `docker exec -it <container_name> bash` и проверьте, что именно у вас смонтировалось в `/var/lib/postgresql/data/`, есть ли в наличии файлы в каталоге `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_wal/`. Если все файлы БД в наличии, то создайте WAL заново: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgresetwal.html

Comment: В контейнер войти нет возможности так как он не поднялся и висит на постоянном рестарте

Comment: Тогда остановите его совсем (например, удалите и создайте заново с запретом на рестарт) и запустите командой `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <cont_name>`